# Executors reused in other class is the best practice?

Tags: android, android-thread

I am using `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);` in Main activity for networking stuff.

**My question** is, for other class or activity i have to use this executor object or i have to do shutdown this Executor at end of my main activity and create new instance in other class or activity?
What is the bast practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fixed thread pool executor maintains a thread.

If you want to run code on the same thread you should use the same executor, if you want to run code on a different thread you should create a new executor.

It does not matter that much if an executor is shared between activities or not, you only need to take care of shutting it down eventually.